# SPServices SPCascade not working in Chrome

Tags: 2010, spservices, cascading

I am using `SPServices (Version : 0.6.2)` with `jQuery version v1.6.4` in SharePoint 2010 environment. I am using `SPCascadeDropdown` function to bind dropdown. It works well in Internet Explorer and Firefox for `Newform.aspx`,`editform.aspx` and `DispForm.aspx`.

But in Chrome, it only works for `editform.aspx` and `DispForm.aspx`. And I am getting below error in `Newform.aspx` and dropdown does not populate values:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null"
```

from `sp.ui.rte.js`

Code is as below:

```
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList:"<LISTNAME>",
    relationshipListParentColumn:"<COLNAME>",
    relationshipListChildColumn:"<COLNAME>",
    parentColumn:"<COLNAME>",
    childColumn:"<COLNAME>",
    debug:false
});
```